# OpenMP - Locks - Deadlock

Tags: c, openmp

I recently came across the following code for OpenMP deadlock. But I am unable to understand the situation. But I found that in second omp section, if we use locka and then lockb there will be no deadlock. Can anyone help me understand this.

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(a, b, nthreads, locka, lockb)
  #pragma omp sections nowait
    {
    #pragma omp section
      {
      omp_set_lock(&locka);
      for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        a[i] = ..

      omp_set_lock(&lockb);
      for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        b[i] = .. a[i] ..
      omp_unset_lock(&lockb);
      omp_unset_lock(&locka);
      }

    #pragma omp section
      {
      omp_set_lock(&lockb);
      for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        b[i] = ...

      omp_set_lock(&locka);
      for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        a[i] = .. b[i] ..
      omp_unset_lock(&locka);
      omp_unset_lock(&lockb);
      }
    }  /* end of sections */
  }  /* end of parallel region */
```

Comment: What is there to understand?  ' if we use locka and then lockb there will be no deadlock' - problem solved.  Always lock in the same order and unlock in the reverse order.  That is already well-known.

Comment: can you also kindly comment the reason for down vote.

Comment: @MartinJames yes i understand your statement. That is how it is done. But can you please explain why with some example. So that it might be useful for beginners like me. Since you knew it, its seems simple to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple. Deadlock happens if first thread locks `locka` and second thread locks `lockb`. What happens next?

First thread wants to lock `lockb`. However, `lockb` is locked by second thread, therefore first thread is blocked and waits for unlocking `lockb`.

Similarly, second thread wants to lock `locka`. However, `locka` is locked by first thread, therefore second thread is blocked and waits for unlocking `locka`.

Both thread are therefore in a blocking state and both wait for unlocking, which never happens, since the unlocking code is below line where threads are blocked.

---

If, in the second `section`, `locka` is locked first, the situation is different. Both threads first try to lock `locka`. However, only one thread is allowed to succeed; this is guaranteed by the OpenMP library. Therefore, only one thread (A) locks `locka` and the other thread (B) is blocked and waits until the `locka` is unlocked.

Thread A then executes its code, since it is not blocked. As it finally unlocks `locka`, thread B is unblocked.

---

In this scenario, deadlock means that both threads are in a blocked state and wait for each other to do something to unblock themselves. In the first case, exactly this can happen, in the second case it can't.

Comment: Perfect !! Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: So no code in the sections are not parallely executed? Since `thread-A` will `locka` till its completely finished, so the second section i.e `thread-B` waits the entire time or vice versa?